# How to 'properly close MFC Modeless Dialogs and fixing resource leak'

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I've created an MFC Application, with a `Base Dialog` (derived from `CDialog` class), a `Setting Dialog` (derived from `CBaseDlg` and an `App Dialog` (also derived from `CBaseDlg`). Then I created a class called `CScrMng` (aka Screen Manager) that hold the `ShowDialog()` function (to `Create` and `Show` these dialogs).

The basic idea is `ScrMng` will manage all of my Modeless Dialogs, and anytime I want to open a dialog, I just need to `CScrMng::ShowDialog()` in the `BaseDlg.cpp`, and the dialog will display.

This approach has caused resources to leak here and there. I've done a bit of research about overriding the `PostNcDestroy()`, but I don't have a clear idea of where to call it.

What function should I use to properly close these modeless dialogs?

I want to open the `Setting Dialog` from `Base Dialog`, then when I click on the `Cancel` button, it should return me to the `Base Dialog` screen so that I can open another Dialog.

Right now I'm using `EndDialog()`. I know it's wrong, but calling `DestroyWindow()` will immediately exit the program, which is not what I want.

**Source code**

MFCApplication.cpp

```
#include...

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CMFCApp::CMFCApp()
{
     // support Restart Manager
     m_dwRestartManagerSupportFlags = AFX_RESTART_MANAGER_SUPPORT_RESTART;
}

CMFCApp theApp;

BOOL CMFCApp::InitInstance()
{
    ...
    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;

    CScrMng::GetInstance()->ShowDialog(IDD_MAINDLG);

    SetRegistryKey(_T("Local Applications"));

    if (pShellManager != NULL)
    {
        delete pShellManager;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

CScrMng.cpp

```
#include...

CScrMng* CScrMng::m_pInstance = NULL;
CScrMng* CScrMng::GetInstance(){
     if (m_pInstance == NULL)
    m_pInstance = new CScrMng();
    return m_pInstance;
}

CScrMng::CScrMng(){}

void CScrMng::ShowDialog(int ID)
{
    CMainDlg* m_pDlg = NULL;
    switch (ID)
    {
    case IDD_MAINDLG:
        m_pDlg = new CMainDlg();
        theApp.m_pMainWnd = m_pDlg;
        m_pDlg->Create(IDD_MAINDLG);
        m_pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        m_pDlg->UpdateWindow();
        break;

    case ...
        break;

    case IDD_SETTINGDLG:
        m_pDlg = new CSettingDlg();
        m_pDlg->Create(ID,NULL);
        m_pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        m_pDlg->UpdateWindow();
        break;
    }
```

CMainDlg.cpp

```
#include...

CMainDlg::CMainDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CMainDlg::IDD, pParent) {m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()-> LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);}

void CMainDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) {...}

void CMainDlg::PostNcDestroy() //Added these
{
    CDialog::PostNcDestroy();
    delete this;
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainDlg, CDialog)
...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CMainDlg::OnInitDialog() {
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        
    return TRUE; 
}

void CMainDlg::OnPaint() {...}

void CMainDlg::OnBnClickedOpenAppdlg()
{
    CScrMng::GetInstance()->ShowDialog(IDD_APPDLG);
}

void CMainDlg::OnBnClickedOpenSettingdlg()
{
    CScrMng::GetInstance()->ShowDialog(IDD_SETTINGDLG);
}

void CMainDlg::OnBnClickedExit() 
{
     DestroyWindow(); //replaced CDialog::OnCancel() with this.
}
```

Update: After changing the code in the SettingDlg.cpp, i encountered a `Debug Assertion Failed!` problem :

```
void CWnd::MoveWindow(int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, BOOL bRepaint)
{
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL)); //Breakpoint triggered

    if (m_pCtrlSite == NULL)
        ::MoveWindow(m_hWnd, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, bRepaint);
    else
        m_pCtrlSite->MoveWindow(x, y, nWidth, nHeight);
}
```

Here are what i changed in the .cpp file:
SettingDlg.cpp

```
void CSettingDlg::PostNcDestroy()
{
    CMainDlg::PostNcDestroy();
}

void CSettingDlg::OnBnClickedSettingcancel()
{
    DestroyWindow(); //Using destroyWindow rather than EndDialog();
}
```

Comment: You don't call `PostNCDestroy`, the framework calls it. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#postncdestroy) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn017-destroying-window-objects?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Jabberwocky can you give me some advices on how should i close the modeless dialog in my application ?

Comment: An approach often used with a modeless dialog box is to create it and then either show or hide it rather than create and delete it. So the modeless dialog box is created once and then what the user sees is the modeless dialog box is either displayed or not. On the other hand this may just be an exercise and investigation into modeless dialog boxes so feel free to ignore this comment.

Comment: This line of source `theApp.m_pMainWnd = m_pBaseDlg;` in the function `CScrMng::ShowDialog()` should not be there. The `theApp.m_pMainWnd` should be auto populated by the framework and you should not change it since that is the main window of the application.

Comment: @RichardChambers these lines of codes isn't mine. it's from my MFC instructor at my company (i'm an intern). he's code this for me. So, in anychance that you can teach me how to fix tthe code above without changing it too much ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close & Delete a modeless Dialogs.
A proper Way is: Override PostNcDestroy, OnOk() and OnCancel() for the Modeless Dialogs

```
void CBaseDlg::PostNcDestroy()
{
    CDialog::PostNcDestroy();
    delete this;
}
```

.

```
void CBaseDlg::OnOk()
{
   if(!UpdateData(TRUE))
       return;
    DestroyWindow();
}
```

.

```
void CBaseDlg::OnCancel()
{
    DestroyWindow();
}
```

Comment: So when i want to close a dialog, i should call the ```CBaseDlg::OnCancel()``` method, right ?

Comment: Yes, or you can call direct DestroyWindow().  If you have any member variables to check & update, use OnOk().

Comment: I just encountered a new error, can you explain it for me ? (edited above)

Comment: Show us the callstack. If you destroy a window, the window is no longer valid, you want not move a destroyed window.

Comment: Worked for me. Nice (or scary) to see people still using MFC.

Comment: @David  Yes MFC is still alive ;)) I still don't unterstand why the mainstream go to the :NET world.